# Why does the test pass when using the element? method to check the element's existence?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

How do you figure out if elements exist on a page?

The page has a link:

```
<a class="twitter" href="h.....">twitter</a>
```

My page object class is:

```
class Computer
  include PageObject

  link(:twitter_link, :class => "twitterrrrr")

  def element_exists?
    puts @browser.url
    twitter_link?        
  end       
end
```

This page is being used in a Cucumber step definition:

```
Then /the elements should exist/ do
  on(Computer).element_exists?
end
```

The above :class is purposefully wrong, it should really be equal to "twitter" (like the HTML above), but when I call `twitter_link?` the step still passes and doesn't fail.

When I call `.exists?` on `twitter_link` then the test fails, which is correct:

```
def element_exists?
  puts @browser.url
  twitter_link.exists?
end
```

The desired outcome also occurred when I did:

```
def element_exists?
  puts @browser.url
  twitter_link?.should == true
end
```

Anyone know why it passes when I call `twitter_link?` on its own? According to the page-objects gem docs there is supposed to be a method to check for existence out of the box. Is that referring to checking for existence in the page class and NOT on the actual page itself? That is what it seems like it's doing.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the method correctly in the test? `twitter_link?` simply returns `true` or `false`. Test frameworks like RSpec and Cucumber will not fail just because of a `false`. It also sounds like you are doing a `twitter_link.exists?`, which will fail because the test is actually trying to click the link. If you do `twitter_link_element.exists?` you will get the same result as `twitter_link?`.

Comment: You are correct, so what is the correct way to check if the element is present and visible on the page? (Using Watir-wedbdriver)I don't want to click the link like .exists? is doing but just want to make sure it's visible.

Comment: Justin, just put the method in the question.

Comment: Cucumber and using the page_objects gem, in my step defs:  on(UngatedPage).element_exists?

Comment: This is giving me my desired outcome:
    twitter_link?.should == true

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do the assertions within the page object rather than within the test? I find the latter to be the more common approach.

Comment: I would do it in the test but the step def was getting very long b/c I was asserting 20+ elements on the page, any easy way to assert 20+ elements on the page using page_objects instead of having a long list, either in the page object or test?

Comment: Unless you have some naming convention or always check all elements of the page object, you will have to list which elements to check.

Comment: Ok, I did this but it keeps clicking the link, how to avoid clicking the links:

elements = [partner_logo, verify_btn, lock_text, lock_icon, what_text, contact, partner, dev, twitter_link, facebook, privacy, terms]
    
    elements.each { |x| x?.should == true }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `twitter_link?` simply returns true or false. Test frameworks like RSpec and Cucumber will not fail just because something returned false. They only fail if an assertion fails or an exception occurs.

In other words, instead of just calling the `twitter_link?` method, you need to check it in an assertion. For example:

```
# Examples using should syntax
page.twitter_link?.should == true
page.twitter_link_element.should exist

# Examples using expect syntax
expect(page.twitter_link?).to be_true
expect(page.twitter_link_element).to exist
```

If you want to check a series of elements, you can create an array of the element names and then iterate through them.

```
elements = [:twitter_link]
elements.each { |x| self.send( "#{x.to_s}?").should == true }
```

Note that when creating the array of elements, you do not want to use `elements = [twitter_link]`. By having `twitter_link` in the array, it will call the method to actually try to click the link. That is why you need to use something like a string or symbol instead. Storing the page object element would also be an option:

```
elements = [twitter_link_element]
elements.each { |x| x.exists?.should == true }
```

Comment: This one worked for me:

elements = [:twitter_link]
elements.each { |x| self.send( "#{x.to_s}?").should == true }